# regex exclude match from capture

Tags: c#, regex

Using Regex in .Net

I will have a set of data that comes in something like this

```
< Bunch o' Data Here >
```

where `<` is just the indicator of a new record and `>` is the end of the record.

these records may come in like this

```
< Dataset 1><Dataset 2 broken, no closing tag <dataset 3>
```

they could also come in as

```
< Dataset 1>Dataset 2 broken, no opening tag ><dataset 3>
```

although, i'm not certain that this latter case is possible, and i'll cross that bridge when i have to.

I'm trying to use Regex to split these into records based on this start and end character, ultimately something like this

```
Match 1 = < Dataset 1>
Match 2 = <Dataset 2 broken, no closing tag 
Match 3 = <Dataset 3>
```

i'm trying to figure out how the non-capturing groups work and maybe my understanding is wrong.

```
<.*?(?:<|>)
```

gets me pretty close i think, except for that it includes the opening character of the 3rd set of data with the capture of the second group.
I also suspect that `?:` is not doing what it needs to and if it take it out, it returns the same set of matches(2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found a simpler solution

```
\<.*?(\>|(?=\<)|$)
```

seems to work.
I've escaped the < > marks for consistency

EDIT: Added $ to allow for un-terminated at end of string

Comment: Using this data set: <Dataset 2 broken, no closing tag < Dataset 1><Dataset 2 broken, no closing tag <dataset 3>Dataset 2 broken, no opening tag >Dataset 2 broken, no opening tag ><Dataset 2 broken, no closing tag <dataset 3><dataset 3><Dataset 2 broken, no closing tag 


Your answer only gets 7 matches.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you have it flipped. You'll want to use `?:` to not capture a group, not `:?`.

```
 <.*?(?:<|>)
```

To expand a bit: the `?` operator within a capture group signifies that you want to do something special. A `:` means to not capture, but there are other operands that you can give the `?` in order to perform other actions. Common ones are look-ahead (`?=`) and look-behind (`?<`), but there are many others.

I also just realized the scope of what you're trying to match (beyond the non-capturing issue). The language of matched parens/brackets/etc is not regular, so - assuming I'm understanding your purpose correctly - you'd need to create a fairly elaborate extended regular expression in order to match what you want. There are a couple of other SO questions about this, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595254/matching-math-expression-with-regular-expression) which has some discussion about it.

Comment: thank you. Sorry, that was a typo in my brain. i looked at my tests and i had it correct. I am using this operator correctly (i think) and as described above with the same results. i'm also trying this with Negative Lookahead (?!) with little success, and am still unsure as to what i could be missing.

Comment: I think you may also be confusing the idea of capturing text vs. consuming it. The ?: prevents text from being captured, meaning that it is not stored anywhere as a separate reference, but the text is still consumed. In other words, text matched within the ?: grouping will not be matched again in subsequent expressions. Although it was not captured, it was already matched (consumed). Does that help some?

Answer (score 1):

What about something simple like this: <[^<>]+>|[^<>]+>|<[^<>]+

Comment: this works great, however these opening and closign tag characters will be comming in from possibly users and i'd like to minimize the find and replace done to build the string.

Comment: Regex ex = new Regex(String.Format("{0}[^{0}{1}]+{1}|[^{0}{1}]+{1}|{0}[^{0}{1}]+", "<", ">")); Something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a *lookahead*, not a non-capturing group.  But simply changing your `:?` (sic) to `?=` won't make the regex work right.  If there's never any text between a closing `>` and the next `<`, try this:

```
<?[^<>]+>?(?=(?:<|$))
```

It works if the closing `>` is missing, but not if the opening `<` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Regex may be the wrong tool for the job.

My first inclination with this would be embed regexreplace in some other language and do it by stages so that you could understand what you did 3 years from now.

If you have potentially missing >'s do

- first pass encloses the line in \< at the start and > at the end.
- a second pass replacing [<>]+ with a single token.  That is, any number of start/stop tokens is replaced with a single token.  Anything that the first step put an extra token on is now fixed.
- your third pass puts an id string at the start before the first token.  The ID is a user code, and a line number
- your final pass actually splits the string into your datasets, but if it gets the wrong number of datasets -- too many or too few, or fails some validation check, then the entire line can be spit back to the creator/editor with a "Problem:  You are short a data field." or other illuminating error.