# Why does Regex.Match include noncapturing groups in the result?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

In matching a regular expression, I want to exclude [noncapturing groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#noncapturing_group) from the result. I incorrectly assumed that they'd be excluded by default since, well, they're called noncapturing groups.

For some reason, though, Regex.Match behaves as though I hadn't even specified a noncapturing group.  Try running this in the Immediate window:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("b3a",@"(?:\d)\w").Value
```

I expected the result to be

```
"a"
```

but it's actually

```
"3a"
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346513/regex-exclude-match-from-capture) suggested I look at the Groups, but there is only one Group in the result and it too is "3a". It contains one Capture, also "3a".

What's going on here? Is Regex bugged, or is there an option I need to set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Matching is not the same thing as capturing. `(?:\d)` simply means match a subpattern containing `\d`, but don't bother putting it in a capture group. Your entire pattern `(?:\d)\w` looks for a `(?:\d)` followed by a `\w`; it's functionally equivalent to `\d\w`.

If you're trying to match a `\w` only when it is preceded by a `\d`, use a lookbehind assertion instead:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("b3a", @"(?<=\d)\w").Value
```

Comment: or `@"\d(\w)"` and use the groups if you want. I find that easier to read (although it may be slower, no idea)

Answer (score 4):

Non-capturing group means it does not make a group. Matching string are included in the resulting string.

If you want exclude that part, use something like lookbehind assertion.

```
@"(?<=\d)\w"
```

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding the purpose of noncapturing groups.

In general, groups (defined by a pair of parentheses `()`) mean two things:

- The contained regular expression is grouped, so any quantifiers after the brackets apply to the whole expression rather than just the previous single character.
- The substring matching the group is stored as a subcapture in the [`Groups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx) property.

Sometimes, you do not want the second result for certain groups, which is why noncapturing groups were introduced: They allow you to group a sub-expression without having any matches of it stored in an item in the `Groups` property.

You have observed that your `Groups` property contains *one* item, though - which is true, as by default, the first group is always the capture of the complete expression. cf. in the docs:

> If the regular expression engine can find a match, the first element of the GroupCollection object returned by the Groups property contains a string that matches the entire regular expression pattern.

---

You can still use groups to achieve what you want, by placing **the string you want to capture** into a group:

```
\d(\w)
```

(I have left out the noncapturing group again as it does not change anything in your above expression.)

With this modified expression, the `Groups` property in your match should have 2 items:

1. The complete match (of `\d\w`)
2. Only the part of the above string you seem to be interested in, matched by `\w`