# regexp matching "not preceded by, unless followed by"

Tags: regex, perl, lisp

Example input string:

```
(F1 (F2 X (Y) Z) (F3 A B)
```

What i want to match: `\w+` that is not preceded by a `(` unless also followed by `)`
In this case: `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `A`, and `B`

A temporary work-around for now (which I know will give me issues later) is `/\(\w+\)| \w+/`, but as it also matches whitespaces, it will cause problems further down the road, especially when it gets to the point of substituting the matches.

I have done some experimenting in the area of negative lookbehind in the form of:

```
/(?!=\()\w+/
```

...but i can't seem to find a way of combining it with *"not preceeded by ("*

Just to be clear:

- The matches in this case are all single letter, but actual data may be multiple characters and may not even be alphanumeric.
- No whitespaces or parentheses can be a part of the returned match.

Comment: I think you need a parser for this, but my regex-fu is weak so someone else might know a way

Comment: So you want to validate parenthesis?

Comment: solved by Joseph Silber: (?<= )\w+(?=[ )])|(?<=\()\w+(?=\))

Comment: If this is related to lisp in that you want to do some processing of lisp data, then using such regexps is generally not going to be a good idea unless you know that the data is very well behaved (for example, no strings, no symbols with weird characters in them like parens, no redundant whitespaces, etc etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<=[ (])\w(?=[ )])
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?2vnri

---

Actually, this might be what you are looking for:

```
(?<= )\w+(?=[ )])|(?<=\()\w+(?=\))
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?2vnro

Comment: @ikegami - Are you referring to the first or the second one?

Comment: Initially both of them worked fine. But upon expanding the example string a bit to include more data, the second one was the one that still served the purpose.

Comment: @Joseph Silber, because I tried it: `say for '(f a b)' =~ /(?<=[ (])\w(?=[ )])/g;`

Comment: @ikegami - Did you follow the link there? You're using my first regex. Take a look at the second one. Here it is again: http://regexr.com/?2vnrr

Comment: @Joseph Silber, I never said anything about your second regex. There was only one when I commented

Answer (score 1):

```
/(?<! [(\w] (?! \w+ \) ) ) \w+/x
```

or

```
/(?<! [(\w] ) \w+ | (?<= \( ) \w+ (?= \) )/x
```

Comment: This one does not obey the "Not preceeded by (", and therefore also matches F1, F2, and F3, which is what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @jarmund, Adjusted to work with your example contrary to your description

Comment: @jarmund uh no, even before my change, it didn't match F1, F2 and F3. (It did match 1, 2 and 3, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to combine the conditions into a regex, you can also simply use a substitution to remove those known to be wrong:

```
my $str = "(F1 (F2 X (Y) Z) (F3 A B)";
$str =~ s/\(\w+(?![)\w])//g;
```

I.e. any opening parentheses, followed by alphanumerics, not followed by closing parenthesis or more alphanumerics.

Then it's a simple matter to extract the alphanumerics:

```
my @items = $str =~ /\w+/g;
say for @items;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a great writeup for matching parenthases with a perl regular expression at: [Matching math expression with regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595254/matching-math-expression-with-regular-expression) However, It's not recomended for any sort of maintainable code. Regular code to do this; however is easy: (psudeocode below)

```
match=true; 
while(match && ch=getchar())
    if(ch==')')
        pop() or match=false
    else if(ch=='(')
        push(ch);
    else if(!isalphanum(ch) &&  ch=!' ')
        match=false;
if(match)
   match=pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method using alternation and lookahead/behind.  This way we can match either a parenthesised token or a token which is not preceded by a parenthesis

```
perl -e '$string="(F1 (F2 X (Y) Z) (F3 A B)";
@params=$string=~/((?<=\()\w+(?=\))|(?<![(\w])\w+)(?!\w)/g;
print join(",",@params),"\n";'

X,Y,Z,A,B
```