# Calculator Logic

Tags: logic, calculator

I'm making a calculator app to challenge myself and I need a hand in planning my logic. Thing is, the equation is in a single string and I need to somehow figure out the numbers on the left and right hand side of an operator which I am evaluating (there is an order of operations) . The challenge is that there are unary operators as well, meaning that I can't just simply assume a number (on either side) is delimited by another operator.

eg - I'm trying to evaluate something like 5+5^-2-3. Order of operations means I focus on the ^ first, so I need to get the 5 and -2, figure them out, then update the equation to be 5+25-3 then evaluate the rest of the operations in order.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: There is a famous algorithm for solving this exact problem. It's called the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this one before. Reverse Polish Notation? It's a good idea, but unfortunately it would be rather hard to implement this considering that everything is passed through as one string. :/

Comment: The shunting yard algorithm is for converting from infix (i.e. 1+2) to RPN.

Comment: @M2065 Don't dismiss this too hastily! The Shunting-yard algo can be supplemented and enhanced to handle precedence and associativity. It's the most powerful algorithm there is for this, short of doing a parser->syntax-tree->tree-eval.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions for this. For example

```
/(\d+)([\+\*])(\d+)/g
```

would match any group of digits either side of a plus or multiplication sign.  Applied to

```
"47+65"
```

would give 3 groups, the first being "47", the second being "+" and the third being "65".

Obviously you would need to consider all the possible operators.   In a more complex equation, you would need to get all matches and perform some conditional checking to determine which group to apply first.  You might also need to consider parentheses - i.e. do they affect the order of operation - and include in the regex

I've create a simple example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UG6vD/1/) (plus, minus, multiply and divide operators only, no spaces between numbers and operators)

**Edit 2:** [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UG6vD/2/) (allows multiple operators in expression and decimal numbers)

**Edit 3:** [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UG6vD/5/) (include power operator - 2^3=8)

**Edit 4:** [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UG6vD/6/) (takes into account parentheses, white space, divide by zero)

Comment: Your solution only handles the most trivial case of only 2 numbers with one operator

Comment: This does provide some help on actually parsing the tokens from the string, but the process of evaluating order of operations and dealing with brackets is not trivial.

Comment: @mclassen, I know, its simple example to show the logic (as asked by OP), not a full solution

Comment: Your solution still does not handle brackets. Solving this problem requires a more abstract mechanism for computing expressions, this answer just leads the OP down the wrong track to actually finding a solution. Maybe you should have your answer just cover the tokenizing aspect of the solution, but don't give an incomplete, ultimately wrong solution to the larger problem at hand.

Comment: @mclaassen, Handling brackets is simply a matter of modifying the function to first matching anything between brackets e.g. `/\(([^()]+)\)/`, then calling itself recursively. There's also other issues to consider such as a leading minus sign, double minus signs, and of course handling invalid input. Again, these can be solved using regular expressions. Please read the first line of my answer (OP need to extract the numbers and operators from a string).  I have not given a solution, just "..a simple example..".

Comment: Technically regex patterns are incapable of matching nested parentheses, because a grammar structure with nested parentheses is not a regular grammar. It is possible with extensions to regex expressions (like in Perl), but its a giant messy hack. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595254/matching-math-expression-with-regular-expression

Comment: Impressive. But the point is that this isn't the way you should do this other than for just getting it to work. Try extending this to support variables, boolean operators etc, it will become a nightmare. If you instead start with logically separate lexing and parsing routines its much easier to extend to add new features.

Answer (score 0):

First a treelike structure comes to mind. But if you want it very simple, depending on the language i'd create an array

`[[5,number],[+,operator1],[5,number],[^,operator3],[-2,number],[-,operator1],[3,number]]`

and then go through that for every operator:

```
1) [[5,number],[+,operator1],[0.04,number],[-,operator1],[3,number]]
2) [[2.04,number]]
```