# Split if not within brackets

Tags: python, regex

This regex problem is stumping me...

I want to split a string by usage of one of the four
basic mathematical operations (+, -, /, *), unless it exists within brackets.

```
Full:
'x^2 * ln(sin(x^2 + y^2)) + 8^(2*9)'

Full Goal:
['x^2', 'ln(sin(x^2 + y^2))', '8^(2*9)']
```

---

```
Simplified Problem:
'x^2 * sin(x^2 + y^2) + 8^(2*9)'

Simplified Goal:
['x^2', 'sin(x^2 + y^2)', '8^(2*9)']
```

A solution to either the Full or Simplified Problem would work.

Comment: what if the brackets are more than one depth deep?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Good catch. I copied over my problem incorrectly from my IDE. I've edited the question to reflect the true problem.

Comment: then this question is not solvable using default re module..

Comment: This can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595254/matching-math-expression-with-regular-expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex cannot be used to reliably solve this issue.  Instead, consider using a very simple state machine where you track whether you are inside braces to determine whether you should split on the math operator.  Here is a very quick attempt that appears to work for your input.

```
math_ops = {'+', '-', '*', '/'}

def parse(inval):
    groups = []
    braces = 0
    part = ''
    for c in f:
        # We add to braces count 
        if c == '(':
            braces += 1
        # We subtract from braces count
        elif c == ')':
            braces -= 1
        # If we are at a math symbol and our brace count is 0, we have a complete part.
        if c in math_ops and braces == 0:
            groups.append(part.strip())
            part = ''
            continue
        part += c
    if part:
        groups.append(part)
    return groups
```

For your two examples the output is:

```
['x^2', 'ln(sin(x^2 + y^2))', ' 8^(2*9)']
['x^2', 'sin(x^2 + y^2)', ' 8^(2*9)']
```

Answer (score 2):

**Simplified problem**

```
def split(string):
    return re.findall(r'(?:[^+\-*/]|\(.*\))+', string)
```

You don't mention stripping spaces, but your example does. If that is desired,

```
def split(string):
    return re.findall(r'(?! )(?:[^+\-*/]|\(.*\))+(?<! )', string)
```

---

**Full problem**

This is a classic example of non-[regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), i.e. not computable by a finite state machine, which is what regular expressions are. Generally speaking, if elements can be nested (e.g. with parens), a regular expression is an insufficient computation model. You need a [pushdown automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton), or a full-blown Turing complete language, like Python.

```
def split(string):
    results = []
    depth = 0
    result = ''
    for c in string + '+':
        if c == '(':
            depth += 1
        elif c == ')':
            depth -= 1
        elif not depth and c in {'+', '-', '*', '/'}:
            results.append(result.strip())
            result = ''
            continue
        result += c
    return results
```

Comment: FYI, you need to append the character in case of hitting a brace as well or the braces are stripped from the segments in results.

Comment: And not to be pedantic, but there is no `trim()` method on Python `str`.  The method you are looking for is `strip()`