# Regex need for the nested curly braces - Perl

Tags: perl

I want to replace the \eqalign{...} into \begin{align*} ... \endalign*} for the below text:

```
$$\eqalign{&amp;\cases{\mathdot{\bf x}=A{\bf x}+Bu\cr y=H{\bf x}}\quad{\rm with}\ {\bf x}=\left(\matrix{x\cr\mathdot{x}\cr\theta\cr\mathdot{\theta}}\right),\cr&amp;A\!=\!\!\left(\matrix{0&amp;1&amp;0&amp;0\cr 0&amp;0&amp;-{m_{a}\over M}g&amp;0\cr 0&amp;0&amp;0&amp;1\cr 0&amp;0&amp;{(M\!+\!m_{a})\over Ml}g&amp;0}\right)\!,\ B\!=\!\left(\matrix{0\cr{a\over M}\cr 0\cr-{a\over Ml}}\right)\!,\ H^{T}\!=\!\left(\matrix{1\cr 0\cr 1\cr 0}\right)\!.}$$
```

Perl Coding

```
my $CurBrLoopMany = qw/((?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*)/;

$inxmlstr=~s/\\eqalign\{($CurBrLoopMany)\}/\\begin{align*}$1\\end\{align*}/gs;
```

However I couldn't able to replace the nested list of braces (square,curly,parenthesis).

Anyone could you please?

Comment: In the given case, you could easily match against line start/end `$$` and the solution is trivial. In turn, in the general case, you are up against an *irregular* language that cannot be parsed with regex. But, Perl's regular expression allows you to do such a thing by its *extensions*. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2595382/1529709) for an example how you could, **but probably not should**, do it.

Comment: You are saying `qw//`, which is _quoted words_. You probably meant `qr//`. In this case it will work anyway because there is only one word in the list, and for that reason it assigns that _word_ to `$CurBrLoopMany`, which in turn can be put as a string containing unescaped meta characters into the `s///`. So you're fine. But still, it's wrong. You want `qr//`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp to search braces `{}` need **one level deeper**.
You don't need **the first global parenthesis** `()`.
At last, like *"simbabque"* say it in its comment, you must use `qr//` code instead of `qw//` code to define a regexp or a piece of regexp.

So you must change your variable like this :

```
my $CurBrLoopMany = qr/(?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*)})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*/;
```

I tried it with success :

```
> cat test
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $inxmlstr = '$$\eqalign{&amp;\cases{\mathdot{\bf x}=A{\bf x}+Bu\cr y=H{\bf x}}\quad{\rm with}\ {\bf x}=\left(\matrix{x\cr\mathdot{x}\cr\theta\cr\mathdot{\theta}}\right),\cr&amp;A\!=\!\!\left(\matrix{0&amp;1&amp;0&amp;0\cr 0&amp;0&amp;-{m_{a}\over M}g&amp;0\cr 0&amp;0&amp;0&amp;1\cr 0&amp;0&amp;{(M\!+\!m_{a})\over Ml}g&amp;0}\right)\!,\ B\!=\!\left(\matrix{0\cr{a\over M}\cr 0\cr-{a\over Ml}}\right)\!,\ H^{T}\!=\!\left(\matrix{1\cr 0\cr 1\cr 0}\right)\!.}$$';
print "BEFORE:      $inxmlstr\n";
my $CurBrLoopMany = qr/(?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*)})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*/;
$inxmlstr =~ s/\\eqalign\{($CurBrLoopMany)\}/\\begin{align*}$1\\end\{align*}/gs;
print "AFTER : $inxmlstr\n";

> ./test
BEFORE:      $$\eqalign{&amp;\cases{\mathdot{\bf x}=A{\bf x}+Bu\cr y=H{\bf x}}\quad{\rm with}\ {\bf x}=\left(\matrix{x\cr\mathdot{x}\cr\theta\cr\mathdot{\theta}}\right),\cr&amp;A\!=\!\!\left(\matrix{0&amp;1&amp;0&amp;0\cr 0&amp;0&amp;-{m_{a}\over M}g&amp;0\cr 0&amp;0&amp;0&amp;1\cr 0&amp;0&amp;{(M\!+\!m_{a})\over Ml}g&amp;0}\right)\!,\ B\!=\!\left(\matrix{0\cr{a\over M}\cr 0\cr-{a\over Ml}}\right)\!,\ H^{T}\!=\!\left(\matrix{1\cr 0\cr 1\cr 0}\right)\!.}$$
AFTER : $$\begin{align*}&amp;\cases{\mathdot{\bf x}=A{\bf x}+Bu\cr y=H{\bf x}}\quad{\rm with}\ {\bf x}=\left(\matrix{x\cr\mathdot{x}\cr\theta\cr\mathdot{\theta}}\right),\cr&amp;A\!=\!\!\left(\matrix{0&amp;1&amp;0&amp;0\cr 0&amp;0&amp;-{m_{a}\over M}g&amp;0\cr 0&amp;0&amp;0&amp;1\cr 0&amp;0&amp;{(M\!+\!m_{a})\over Ml}g&amp;0}\right)\!,\ B\!=\!\left(\matrix{0\cr{a\over M}\cr 0\cr-{a\over Ml}}\right)\!,\ H^{T}\!=\!\left(\matrix{1\cr 0\cr 1\cr 0}\right)\!.\end{align*}$$
```