# Parsing a mathematical string expression in Python using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've built an expression evaluator using an AST and would now like to connect it to a parser. I want to build out the parsing on my own using regular expressions, without relying on tools like Pyparser, or the tokenize library.

Valid symbols: real numbers, +, -, *, /, (, )
Number format: any valid real number with or without a decimal, with an optional positive/negative sign prefixed to it.

```
    num_pattern = r"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+"
    symbol_pattern = "[/+-/*()]"
```

Input is an expression containing a number or symbol, followed by **optional** white space, followed by a number or symbol and repeat.

I want to find each token, strip any whitespace, add a single space, and reassemble the output (which I will then turn into a white space separated list).

My two biggest problems are that the negative sign (-) can appear both as part of a number and as an operator. I'm not sure how to go about separating the two cases. I'm also having difficulty grouping the results together in a way that will let me replace them. I can find all of the numbers in the string, and I can find all of the symbols, but I don't know how to create a single regEx that will break each multi-digit number and each symbol into a group which I can this replace/add a space to. I know this has something to do with using a greedy match, but I'm lost as to how.

Examples:

```
(-23 + 8) * 5   -->   ( -23 + 8 ) * 5
-23--23         -->   -23 - -23
.3 * (-3+ 9)    -->   .3 * ( -3 + 9 )
```

Comment: If you could place some data and examples it would be helpful to visualize. **Only text is boring**

Comment: Can't `.3` appear as `0.3` ?

Comment: @noob In input both are possible. The input will be user generated and it needs to support the same style of input as most scientific calculators (many allow `.3`, some don't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

noob came up with a big part of this expression. But it wasn't quire working the way I wanted to. I made a series of small tweaks to arrive at this:

`((((^|\s)-)?(\d*\.\d+|\d+))|([-+\/*()]))`  with substitution `\1`  (note the space)

There are two main parts. The first is for the numeric part. It will match both implicit positive numbers and explicit negative numbers. It will also handle decimal numbers either in the form `a.b` or `.b` (short for `0.b`) but will reject a `.` with no numbers to the right.

`(((^|\s)-)?(\d*\.\d+|\d+))`

The `((^|\s)-)?` portion handles the optional negative sign. To keep negation separate from subtraction there is a constraint that a negative number either be prefixed with a space or that it comes at the beginning of the string.

The second portion `([-+\/*()]))` simply matches for a single operator from the list.

Examples:

```
-3              -->     -3
-3+3            -->     -3 + 3
3-3             -->     3 - 3
3--3            -->     3 - - 3 (user error)
3- -3           -->     3 - -3
2+(-3+5)        -->     2 + ( - 3 + 5 ) (user error)
2 + ( -3 + 5)   -->     2 + ( -3 + 5 )
-0.3            -->     -0.3
0.3+.5          -->     0.3 + .5
-.3             -->     -.3
-.3-0.5         -->     -.3 - 0.5
```

Comment: ▲ I was treating ((^|\s)-)? as two different expressions. Glad you did it. You could had added this to my solution which was almost there. Why did you chose to post it differently and change the accept vote ?

Answer (score 2):

Taking into consideration numbers like `-23` and `.3` I have came up with following solution which uses `alteration` for three cases.

**Regex:** `((-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?))|([-+\/*()])|(-?\.\d+))`

**Explanation:**

- `((-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?))` matches any signed negative or positive number with decimal part.
- `([-+\/*()])` matches any of the tokens.
- `(-?\.\d+))` matches the signed number which have **only** decimal part. Like `.3`.

**Replacement to do:** Replace with **`\1`**  i.e `First captured group` `space`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xL1gY6/1)**

Comment: How are you going to deal e.g. with nested parentheses?

Comment: @bereal: Let's deal with it now. This solution is just a start to give head's up to OP. I am working on nested thing now.

Comment: Just to save you some hours: Python `re` does not support recursion, so parentheses matching is not possible.

Comment: @bereal: Could you please check my [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xL1gY6/2). I think it's already dealing with nested parenthesis.

Comment: It also matches things like `)(+*-/(`. Without `/g` it doesn't match almost anything.

Comment: As the OP mentioned _Input is an expression containing a number or symbol, followed by optional white space, followed by a number or symbol and repeat._ I think this regex works. If we consider every scenario It's going to be complicated and multistep parsing.

Comment: @noob This seems to work for many of the input expressions I tried, however it fails on something like `3-2` which it replaces with `3 -2` but should be `3 - 2`. I need to somehow tell it that for the special case of a negative symbol, it the sign *follows* a number it should be treated as a match, or to put it another way, if two numbers appear consecutively then there is an input error.

Comment: @BrianHVB: What is source of input ? User or some other function ?

Comment: @noob Ultimately the user. I could add a constraint that all negative symbols must be be prefixed with a space, but I don't like doing one-off cases like that since the other ops don't require it.......Now I know why most calculators have a different button for minus and negative.  I will work on a separate regEx that handles only negative signs and will prefer them as an operator instead of part of the number when both are possible.

Comment: @BrianHVB: My point is why write as `3 - 2` when second number is definitely going to have -ve sign. I mean mathematically `3 - 2` is `3 + (-2)` which results in `3 - 2`.

Comment: @noob Mathematically it works but then I would need to generate the implicit '+' sign as part of the output so that the AST could handle it. The job of my parser is to simply make a tokenized list, not to check to mathematical correctness. I already have that taken care of. The problem is that `3-2` is a simple case and should produce a simple three token list.......How would I change your solution to reverse the assumption so that only negatively signed numbers preceded by either a space or the beginning of input are matched?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107256/discussion-between-noob-and-brianhvb).

Comment: I ended up using the following:
((((^|\s)-)?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?))|([-+\/*()])|(-?\.\d+))

Answer (score 1):

I prefer named groups for that:

```
((?P<brackets>[()])|(?P<number>\-?\d*\.?\d+)|(?P<operator>[+\-\*\/]))
```

See example https://regex101.com/r/dW4hP0/2

Then use re.finditer and groupdict on match.

Comment: You will fail on `1-2`

Answer (score 1):

While you might get a long way with regexes you'll bump into an inevitable road block. Regular expression code can only parse Chomsky type 2 grammars (also called regular expressions or context free grammars), while math formulae are of type 3, which is a superset. Especially nested expressions will cause trouble.

So you could use regexes for scanning, but after that you'll need a parser with a kind of stack mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

It's not exactly clear what you want to do.

If you're attempting to parse a math expression with a regular expression, then you're out of luck, regexps are not powerful enough to do that (actually, you cannot even match parenthesis with regexps only: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595254/matching-math-expression-with-regular-expression))

If you are attempting to differentiate the operator `-` from the mathematical `-`, you're also out of luck : to do that you need semantic analysis in most cases and you cannot do that 'inline' with a regular expression.

Lastly, you have an error in your numerical patter (the final `?` has to include the numerical part or it won't work as expected):

```
num_pattern = r"[-+]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?"
```

Comment: I'm attempting to create a list of tokenized symbols which I can feed into an AST evaluator that I already created. Also I don't need to balance parenthesis or do anything special if they are mismatched, as my AST will already do this, I just need them to appear as discrete items in a list.