# Regex for polynomial expression

Tags: java, regex, polynomials

I have a string that I hope is a polynomial expression, something like `"2x^2-3x+1`. I want to use a regex to group each term in the expression. I currently have `"^(-?\d?x(\^\d)?)+"`. I'm trying to capture a term as an optional minus sign, then a number, then x, then an optional exponent, which should be of the form "^someNumber". So for my above polynomial, I'd want group 1 to be `"2x^2"`, group 2 to be `"-3x"` and group 3 to be `"+1"`. Firstly, if I have `(someGroupExpression)+`, will this generate a group for each someGroupExpression that occurs? Secondly, for the exponent part, I don't want to have it be a nested group, as this would make it troublesome to loop through the term groups. How can I specify that the rules the exponent part should follow without making it a group? Please let me know if I can clarify the question.

Comment: Use a noncapturing group?

Comment: Non capturing group! That's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for for the second part of my question. Thank you, I tried googling, but I guess I used bad phrasing, and never came across that concept.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438736/ruby-regex-to-capture-any-numerical-characters-in-a-string/36438777#36438777).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture each sub expression in a group which is not nested or overlapping use the following regex.

**Regex:** `([+-]?[^-+]+)`

**Explanation:** It will capture each sub expression of whole without overlapping each match.

**Java Code**

```
String exp = "2x^3+4x^2+5x-42";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([+-]?[^-+]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(exp);
int x=0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    x=x+1;
    System.out.println("Group "+x+": " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

**[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/nI5oA5/1)**

**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/cgaleS)**

---

A more robust regex which considers all sub-expressions would be:

**Regex:** `([+-]?(?:(?:\d+x\^\d+)|(?:\d+x)|(?:\d+)|(?:x)))`

***Use `\\` in Java for double escaping. `\d` will become `\\d`, `\^` becomes `\\^`.***

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nI5oA5/6)**

**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/v8jZBj)**

Comment: @nilcit: Okay I will modify it then. I am checking only for separating symbols within the expression like `+` and `-` which allowed any coefficient. Also note that the green check mark is for **Accepting answer**. So accept only when you are sure this is the **Solution**. If it's helpful then Upvote but think before accepting an answer.

Comment: I've tried to understand your solution myself a bit, and came up with the following: `([+-]?[^-\^+\\]+x(?:\^[^-\^+x\\])?)` - I intend this for a calculator type app, so the only symbols the user may input are decimal numbers, and the plus, minus, divide, multiply symbols, and the `x` symbol. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @nilcit: The regex you came up with is leaving the last number without coefficient. Check it out again.

Comment: @nilcit: [This one is a bit long. But I have considered all possible cases within expression.](https://regex101.com/r/nI5oA5/6)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108587/discussion-between-noob-and-nilcit).

Comment: noob came up with the following solution: `([+-]?(?:(?:\d+x\^\d+)|(?:\d+x)|(?:\d+)|(?:x)))`, it works in all cases that I would like to capture

Comment: How can I add matcher for let’s say 2x^-2? So the exponent is -2.