# Checking form of a string c++

Tags: c++, string

So.. I am doing a program in which I ask the user to input a string (which is a polynomial) and I want it to have the following structure:
+/- (number from 0 to 9) (x) (number from 0 to 9) . And what is in brackets may or may not appear, so basically something like "+2x-4x3" would be accepted but "+2xx3--2x" not, or "+-x2" also not. And I want my program to run a test and check if the input data has this structure or not. So, after I store the input data in a string called "p", I am using the following loop to check if the characters are x, +, - or a number, but I can't find the way to make this more precise and check for the other possible mistakes ... Any suggestions?

```
for (unsigned int i=0; i<p.length(); i++) {
    if ((p[i] < '0' ||  p[i] > '9') && p[i]!='+' && p[i] !='-' && p[i]!='x'  ) {

    std::cout << "Error.";
    return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Do you know [regular expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)?

Comment: @pasbi: "I have 1 problem, someone said to use regex, now I have 2 problems." :-)

Comment: Why not using regex here? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490757/regex-for-polynomial-expression

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the grammar of your expression more closely (as written, your accept single `+`).

```
Exprs : Expr $ // End of input
      | Expr Exprs

Expr : sign [digits] x [digits] // I change you definition here as you accept sign only
     | sign digits

sign : + | -

digits : digit
        | digit digits

digit: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

Then, we might begin the parsing/lexing functions

```
bool accept_sign(const char*& s) {
    if (*s != '-' && *s != '+') return false;
    ++s;
    return true;
}

bool accept_digits(const char*& s) {
    if (!std::isdigit(*s)) return false;
    while (std::isdigit(*s)) ++s;
    return true;
}

bool accept_x(const char*& s) {
    if (*s != 'x' /*&& *s != 'X'*/) return false;
    ++s;
    return true;
}
```

`Expr` might be changed to allow simple look ahead:

```
Expr : sign x [digits]
     | sign digits x [digits]
     | sign digits
```

```
bool accept_Expr(const char*& s) {
    if (!accept_sign(s)) { return false; }
    if (accept_x(s)) { accept_digits(s); return true; }
    if (!accept_digits(s)) { return false; }
    if (accept_x(s)) { accept_digits(s); }
    return true;
}
```

```
bool accept_Exprs(const char*& s) {
    while (accept_Expr(s)) {/* empty */}
    return *s == '\0';
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/078939bb227a89ec)

Alternatively, you might turn the grammar into regex:

`^([+-](\d*x\d*|\d+))+$` (or avoiding capture group [`^(?:[+-](?:\d*x\d*|\d+))+$`](https://regex101.com/r/hutahK/1))

```
const std::string tests[] = {"+3x", "+4x2-3", "+-2x", "+3xx"};
const std::regex regex(R"(^(?:[+-](?:\d*x\d*|\d+))+$)");

for (auto s : tests) {
    std::cout << s << (std::regex_match(s, regex) ? " is a valid polynomial\n"
                                                  : " is not a valid polynomial\n");
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/300466e988987b63)