# PHP Validate that a string is a mathematical expression

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a PHP function to check if a string represents a mathematical expression.

This is what I have:

```
function is_math( $maybe_math ){
    $pattern = '([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+[\/\+\-\*])+([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9])';
    if( 0 === preg_match( $maybe_math, $pattern ) ){
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am testing with these possibilities:

```
$valid = is_math( '(1-4*(9*5/1)+1)' ); //true
$invalid = is_math( 'hats'  ); //false
$valid_and_invalid = is_math( '(1-4aaa*(9*5/1)+1k)' ); //true
```

As you can see, so far it evaluates true for a mathematical expression, or a string with valid math characters and invalid math characters. Right now the third test I am showing should be false, since there are letters in it and I am not doing algebra here.

My goal here is to create a function I can use to validate that my string can be passed to eval and get a number back and not risk execution of unsafe code, as these numbers come partially from POST data.

Comment: So what is the problem now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching math expression with regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595254/matching-math-expression-with-regular-expression). Check answer with php solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2596378/2253302

Comment: use php eval function and yes this question is duplicate

Comment: @Rizier123 - The third possible input I showed evaluated true, but it has letters. Those are not numbers or math operators. How to make it evaluate false when any none numbers of math operators are passed?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the one that alexander.polomodov, as that answer allows for letters for use when doing algebra, I'm trying to validate a string before passing to eval(). I want to make sure it will give me a valid response and is not an attempt to execute something unsafe through eval.

Comment: @JPollock Just remove all characters which you don't allow in your math expression.

Comment: Why isn't `hats` the product of `h`, `a`, `t` and `s` mathematically? Wild guess: It's because `sin` is not the product of `s`, `i` and `n` either?

Comment: @  Rizier123 - I don't want to remove them, they should be removed, at this point, but I need to validate that process. This is the last safety check before eval().

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem is that you're only looking at the smallest possible matching substring, rather than the entire expression.

You can [see for yourself](https://regex101.com/r/pI4tA4/1) what's being matched from these expressions.

First step would be to wrap your expression in start and end matches (`^` and `$`, respectively), include your full set of allowed characters (you have no match for `(` or `)`, for example) and go on from there.

But really, this is a fool's errand. A regular expression is not designed to parse mathematical expressions; there's some learning value to this exercise, but ultimately it simply can't be done well.