# How to skip linebreak and compare maths in Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

I have 50 results on [100 pages](http://www.solidzapps.com/) of the kind:

```
Duration: 5 minutes | **238 views
2 likes** | 0 dislikes
```

I want to highlight results which have a view response higher than one like every 50 views, and more than 5 likes:

```
... | **238 views
9 likes**
```

(probably using regex?) line break is /s/S and the [regex maths operations are difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595254/matching-math-expression-with-regular-expression)...

So far i have found that i can highlight chrome regex results in chrome console via:

```
var p=/(\>{1}[^\n\<]*?)([^\n\<]{0,30}regu[^\n\<]{0,10})/gi,b=document.body;
b.innerHTML=b.innerHTML.replace(p,'$1<span style="background-color:red;">$2</span>');
```

Comment: Is there a reason you using regex for this? Is an answer without regex okay?

Comment: Yes please, that would be cool!

Comment: alright I almost have an answer finished, just need a couple more minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Copy and paste into chrome console

```
$("#pageResults li").each(function (){

    var viewsText = $(this).find(".duration-viewCount").text();
    var numViews = +viewsText.match(/\|\s([^ ]+)/)[1].replace(/,/g, "");

    var likesText = $(this).find(".likes").text();
    var numLikes = +likesText.match("^([^ ]+)")[1].replace(/,/g, "");

    //i think numlikes * 50 > numViews is what you're looking for, change that if not
    if (numLikes > 5 && numLikes * 50 > numViews)
    {
        $(this).css("background-color", "lightgreen");
    }

});
```

Looks like:
[image]

Comment: That's incredible.  Very awesome indeed. previously i was confused, slow, eyes were scanning like crazy. now i am able to find many results and to genuinely search YT. thanks.

Comment: Can i please ask something extra? How can I copy the corresponding YT links into a text list on the console? so i can copy them to a blog of the best videos as lists?