# Python: Extract math equations or expressions from string

Tags: python, regex

I have multiple input files with a list of questions including few math questions, I'm trying to extract only the math equations

Example Input File:

1. Evaluate the following equation y = mx + c, where m is slope and c is intercept
2. Rearrange the following: overflow stack
3. Find x if 2^3 = 2x
4. Find x if {(2x+3)* (23x+3)} = 256

Desired output:

1. y = mx + c
2. NA
3. 2^3 = 2x
4. {(2x+3)* (23x+3)} = 256

I've so far tried regex to parse "=" and extract left side and right side parts separately but it does run into errors (especially for the last one)

Comment: `tried regex [...] but it does run into errors`: Show us what you have tried and what went wrong.

Comment: You may want to read the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595254/matching-math-expression-with-regular-expression

Answer (score 0):

Since mathematics is presented in very many different patterns, I would approach this by creating a tuple of math patterns.

Start by separating every line into its own string, and making a pattern that will extract what you want from it. Then add the pattern that made the extraction to the tuple. A quick example I made below. The for-loop I made is not the best, but should demonstrate the solution well enough:

```
import re


t1 = 'Evaluate the following equation y = mx + c, where m is slope and c is intercept'
t2 = 'Rearrange the following: overflow stack'
t3 = 'Find x if 2^3 = 2x'
t4 = 'Find x if {(2x+3)* (23x+3)} = 256'


math_patterns = (r'((y|x)\s*=\s*.+),', r'if\s(.+)', r'({.+)')


for pattern in math_patterns:

    if re.search(pattern, t1):
        print(re.search(pattern, t1).group(1))
        continue

    if re.search(pattern, t3):
        print(re.search(pattern, t3).group(1))
        continue

    if re.search(pattern, t4):
        print(re.search(pattern, t4).group(1))
        continue
```

Will output the following:

```
y = mx + c
2^3 = 2x
{(2x+3)* (23x+3)} = 256
```